Network VLAN and Subnet Architecture/Design/Setup Advice
I'm currently in the process of re-configuring parts of my home network and have been trying to get my head around networks, subnets, VLANs, and all that stuff. While I've done my best to read up and learn what I can from here and other places, unfortunately I'm not the kind of person who learns well through reading through tutorials and lessons, so I'm not 100% sure I have it so I wanted to ask for any advice or thoughts.
Devices: a few PCs or regular devices; a homelab-style server running some VMs and Docker containers, a QNAP NAS, Asus RT-AX82U routerAP; and some IoT devices.
I know that the current router won't be able to do what I want, so I intend on replacing it with another server/firewall/router like the Qotom Q20331G9 or Gowin GW-R86S or GW-BS-1UR2 in the coming months running pfSense or OPNSense, this post is about planning the networks so that once I get it, I have a solid setup plan and understanding of what's going to work.
My original plan was as follows:









10.32.0.0/16
Overall IP Range


10.32.1.0/24
Main Device Network


10.32.51.0/24
Docker - Net01


10.32.52.0/24
Docker - Net02


10.32.53.0/24
Docker - Net03


10.32.54.0/24
Docker - Net04


10.32.55.0/24
Docker - Net05


10.32.56.0/24
Docker - Net06


10.32.99.0/24
Guest Network


10.32.104.0/21
IoT Network



Why 10.32? I don't need the full 10.* range so 32 seemed like a good number.
The new server would be at 10.42.1.1 and act as a DHCP server with a range of 10.32.1.100 to 10.32.1.254 (some static devices below 99), and I would use my RT-AX82U as an AP on that network.
My main Docker Lab/Server would sit at 10.42.1.50, thus why I liked setting the docker networks to be 10.42.5x.xx. From what I've read and learnt, communicating between the Docker networks means going through the router (which in this case is the Docker host) so that works fine. And with the host being on the main network, it can communicate with other devices on the main network without drama.
I wanted to have IoT devices on a separate server for security reasons, however, because they will need to be able to communicate with a couple of the Docker containers as well as a Home Assistant VM running on the server (e.g; with an IP address of 10.42.1.51), which is where I now hit the limits of my knowledge.
Some of the questions I have are:
Would I need another AP to service these IoT devices?
Would that AP then also have to act as a DHCP server for 10.32.104.1 to 10.32.111.254?
And ultimately, while I believe that I should be able to configure the new router to allow these networks to talk to each other, is that the 'best' way to do it? Or should I be splitting or combining the networks differently?

I understand that you might want to do this just for the sake of it, but: From my perspective, this appears to be incredibly over-engineered. Do you even need Docker containers directly on the network? Do you really want multiple broadcast domains? Think device/service discovery. Also, about IoT over Wi-Fi: Most access points can’t even handle 50 connected clients. A subnet for 2046 devices appears way oversized in relation.

@DanielB: I am guessing that was a typo for /24, but not all addressing plans are "pack as tightly as possible" – even cheap home routers use /24 instead of squeezing those 50 clients into a /26. (At work, lacking a proper inventory system, we went with /16s for subnets that have 30-50 devices just for the convenience of "10.48.[office#].[computer#]", because we still had tons of 10.x address space to spare after that, and it makes literally no difference in performance anyway.)

@DanielB It is to some extent over-engineered, but at the same time most of this exists in my current environment. I run multiple Docker networks, some are internal only to isolate containers, others connect to VPNs or are just passed through.
grawity_u1686 wasn't necessarily a typo. I 100% don't need 2046 devices, but rather than limiting myself to just ~250 I wanted to 'future proof' in the event I end up with too many. Like you said, I don't see a performance issue with the spare addresses and I can configure security on the Gateway or AP.


Would I need another AP to service these IoT devices?

Depends. Many higher-grade APs have support for hosting multiple SSIDs, each bridged to a different 802.1Q-tagged VLAN – e.g. UniFi with controller (but not standalone), or any Mikrotik product, or many (though not all) devices running OpenWrt – but if your APs do not support VLANs, then you'll need an additional one.

Would that AP then also have to act as a DHCP server for 10.32.104.1 to 10.32.111.254?

Access points aren't really supposed to act as DHCP servers at all. They are Ethernet-layer bridges (as opposed to full-on "wireless routers" which are routers) and usually the job of an AP is just to forward every Ethernet frame into the wired VLAN where the actual router and DHCP server are.
The subnet's router is a more suitable place for a DHCP server, though it can be any device directly attached to the subnet (indeed even an AP, though that's slightly weird).
Note, if you plan to place the DHCP server somewhere unusual, then either the server needs to have direct (bridged) connection to that subnet, or there needs to be a "DHCP relay" in that subnet that'd forward requests across. (As I understood it, you want to have 10.32.{99,104}.0/24 routed by router A but want to serve DHCP from a docker container on host B which has no direct connection to those subnets – DHCP relaying would be needed in this situation.)

And ultimately, while I believe that I should be able to configure the new router to allow these networks to talk to each other, is that the 'best' way to do it? Or should I be splitting or combining the networks differently?

It's literally the job of a router to allow these networks to talk to each other.
When you have all of them on a single router, it automatically knows the routes to all of the subnets that it's attached to – the only thing you'd need to configure is firewall rules (e.g. pfSense comes with "block by default" firewall at first).
When you have more than one router (let's say an off-the-shelf one for general LAN routing plus the Docker host as a second router), then routes from each router towards the other router's subnets need to be defined – at least when they need to differ from the "default" route. Make sure your LAN gateway allows you to define static routes; it's often left out from the config UI in low-end devices.
It might be useful to plan your subnet numbering so that they could be aggregated into fewer routes; e.g. if you restrict your Docker subnets to 48–63, then they can all be handled by a single 10.32.48.0/20 route, saving you a little bit of manual static-route configuration.
(Something like OSPF or at least RIP for automatic route distribution might be a good future exercise once you have 3 or more routers.)

Really appreciate the explanation here! I have enough knowledge to get myself into trouble but not enough to get out of it so your breakdown helped with the simple Yes/No/Maybes.
I don't think my AP will handle two subnets, but I have some old spare ones I can flash WRT onto and use for now.
A new router/DHCP server running pfSense is on the cards.
But for now, I will try to re-do the numbering like you mentioned to consolidate routes. That was the part I didn't fully understand so will crack out a new plan.
Again, really appreciate the advice!

The current numbering is fine, since the 50-59 subnets are already in the middle of 48-63.

You had me thinking, rather than arbitrary numbers, tightening it up.
Would this be 'better'?
10.32.0.0/18 - Overall |
10.32.1.0/24 - Main |
10.32.11.0/24 - Guest |
10.32.12.0/22 - IoT - 10.32.12.1-254 |
|
10.32.32.0/20 - Server1 Docker Range - 10.32.32.1-254 |
10.32.32.0/24 - DkrS1 Net01 - 10.32.32.1-254 |
to |
10.32.47.0/24 - DkrS1 Net16 - 10.32.47.1-254 |
|
10.32.32.0/20 - Sv2 Docker Range - 10.32.32-254 |
10.32.32.0/24 - DkrS2 Net01 - 10.32.32.1 - 10.32.32.254 |
to |
10.32.47.0/24 - DkrS2 Net16 - 10.32.47.1 - 10.32.47.254 |
